# JAX_RS resources and EJB lifecycle mismatch

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, ejb, jax-rs

JAX-RS resources (class annotated with @Path) have a per-request default lifecycle.

Now EJBs have their own lifecycle too,I mean when have a reference to an EJB, this reference actually is the reference of a proxy object that manages a pool of EJBs.

How do these lifecycle models coexist when an EJB is also a JAX-RS resource ?

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html

> JAX-RS resources are managed in per-request scope by default which
>   means that new resource is created for each request.

source:
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html

Answer (score 1):

> JAX-RS works with Enterprise JavaBeans technology (enterprise beans)
>   and Contexts and Dependency Injection for Java EE (CDI).
>
> In general, for JAX-RS to work with enterprise beans, you need to
>   annotate the class of a bean with @Path to convert it to a root
>   resource class. You can use the @Path annotation with stateless
>   session beans and singleton POJO beans.
>
> JAX-RS and CDI have slightly different component models. By default,
>   JAX-RS root resource classes are managed in the request scope, and no
>   annotations are required for specifying the scope. CDI managed beans
>   annotated with @RequestScoped or @ApplicationScoped can be converted
>   to JAX-RS resource classes.

For a web application to use a bean that injects another bean class, the bean needs to be able to hold state over the duration of the user's interaction with the application. The way to define this state is to give the bean a scope

- **@RequestScoped:** A user's interaction with a web application in a single HTTP request.
- **@SessionScoped:** A user's interaction with a web application across multiple HTTP
  requests.
- **@ApplicationScoped:** Shared state across all users' interactions with a web application.
- **@Dependent:** The default scope if none is specified; it means that an object
  exists to serve exactly one client (bean) and has the same lifecycle
  as that client (bean).
- **@ConversationScoped:** A user's interaction with a servlet, including JavaServer Faces
  applications. The conversation scope exists within
  developer-controlled boundaries that extend it across multiple
  requests for long-running conversations. All long-running
  conversations are scoped to a particular HTTP servlet session and may
  not cross session boundaries.

Answering your question, just as you can do Contexts and Dependency Injection one inside another, each bean will manage its own state independently. And depending on the role you are going to perform you must define a scope for it.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-advanced004.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-basic008.htm#GJBBK

Comment: Thanks for your question, but I still don't understand.  How is the pool model of EJBs compatible with the per request model of JAX-RS resources ?

Answer (score 0):

What EJB provides is a a single dedicated thread per client request and transaction.
You can think for example of each Stateless bean as an thread instance instantiated with (injected) data waiting to serve a request. 
When a bean is created  injection takes place and  and after each method invocation (REST in your case) will return to a pool for re-use or destroyed.
So there is a match between REST "per-request default lifecycle" and The SLSB lifecycle.